# Turn wrapped in an Java object warning in error (to use safeUnbox method)

Tags: android, build, lint

Is there any configuration to turn this warnings in errors when you're running gradlew lint check?

The example message is like this:

> w: warning: viewModel.progressVisibility.getValue() is a boxed field
>   but needs to be un-boxed to execute android:visibility.

Comment: this probably could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707901/android-set-all-lint-warnings-as-errors-except-for-certain-ones

Comment: Tried this changes @VladyslavMatviienko. No changes on the lint report. Still showing as a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54321834/6100078, you need to add this line on the application gradle:

```
android {

...

kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 1000)
        option("-Werror")
    }
}
```

This will make any build warning be reported as error.